# contents are not caching using manifest

Tags: html, asp.net, caching, browser-cache, cache-manifest

I have created `manifest` file, `app1.manifest` as below.

1. I took `Text` file from `Visual Studio`.
2. named is as `app1.manifest`.
3. Wrote content in that as below

   CACHE:

   App_Themes/DatePicker.css

   App_Themes/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css

   App_Themes/Leap.css

   App_Themes/Leap_New.css

   App_Themes/menu.css

   App_Themes/menu_New.css

   App_Themes/sumoselect.css

   App_Themes/validationEngine.jquery.css
4. Referenced that as `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="../../Manifest/Leap.manifest"  type="text/cache-manifest">`

But contents are not coming from cache.

[image]

in chrome.

**Edit**

This is how my html header looks like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="../../Manifest/Leap.manifest" type="text/cache-manifest">
```

Comment: Could you show us the header's html of the page you are seeing this

Comment: no, that's the `<html>` tag declaration, I mean the content between the tags `<header></header>`

Comment: My team leader was so desperate, he quit on this. Thanks for help